# How do I execute a SQL Server stored procedure from Informatica Developer (10.1, not Power Center)

Tags: sql-server, informatica

I am trying to execute (call) a SQL Server stored procedure from Infa Developer, I created a mapping (new mapping from SQL Query). I am trying to pass it runtime variables from the previous mapping task in order to log these to a SQL Server table (the stored procedure does an `INSERT`). It generated the following T-SQL query:

```
?RETURN_VALUE? = call usp_TempTestInsertINFARunTimeParams (?Workflow_Name?, ?Instance_Id?, ?StartTime?, ?EndTime?, ?SourceRows?, ?TargetRows?)
```

However, it does not validate, the validation log states 'the mapping must have a source' and '... must have a target'. I have a feeling I'm doing this completely wrong. And: this is not Power Center (no sessions, as far as I can tell).

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Developer is a client tool still using PowerCenter. And a mapping needs source and target - just as it says in the log. Can you show the mapping?

Comment: Conceptually I do understand that any mapping needs a source and a target, but if I only execute a stored procedure in that mapping (or an INSERT) to which I am passing parameters and I don't need the return value, then I really don't need either. I guess I'm thinking in SSIS terms. So let me rephrase the question, what do you use as a source and target around a SQL transformation? I created a flat file as a target where the SQLError and the RETURN_VALUE go, but what should I use as a Source when the actual source are user variables in the workflow? I don't know how to export a mapping, sorry.

Comment: The whole idea that I have to create a source and target that I don't really use just to make the mapping work makes me think I'm getting this completely wrong... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now with the comments I can confirm and answer your question:

Yes, Soure and Target transformations in Informatica are mandatory elements of the mapping. It will not be a valid mapping without them. Let me try to explain a bit more.

The whole concept of ETL tool is to Extract data from the Source, do all the needed Transformations outside the database and Load the data to required Target. It is possible - and quite often necessary - to invoke Stored Procedures before or after the data load. Sometimes even use the exisitng Stored Procedures as part of the dataload. However, from ETL perspective, this is the additional feature. ETL tool - here Informatica being a perfect example - is not meant to be a tool for invoking SPs. This reminds me a question any T-SQL developer asks with his first PL-SQL query: what in the world is this DUAL? Why do I need 'from dual' if I just want to do some calculation like SELECT 123*456? That is the theory.

Now in real world it happens quite often that you NEED to invoke a stored procedure. And that it is the ONLY thing you need to do. Then you do use the DUAL ;) Which in PowerCenter world means you use DUAL as the Source (or actually any table you know that exists in the source system), you put `1=2` in the `Source Filter` property (or put the `Filter Transforation` in the mapping with `FALSE` as the condition), link just one port with the target. Next, you put the `Stored Procedure` call as Pre- or Post-SQL property on your source or target - depending on where you actually want to run it.

Odd? Well - the odd part is where you want to use the ETL tool as a trigger, not the ETL tool ;)

Comment: Yes, thank you, I completely understand. It's just hard to believe that they (Informatica) didn't think of providing a better way to log (write to a table) system provided parameters. I am trying to use a SP because I want to re-use it. And then, why did they make the SQL statement a transformation? That's why Microsoft (in SSIS) makes a SQL Task a Control Flow and not a Data Flow... Anyhow, I will explore your solution and mark your answer once I get it to work. The problem is, I don't see Pre and Post properties on sources and targets in Informatica Developer? Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not using the Developer. I'll wait as long as possible - till it's useful, before I switch :) SQL Transformation should be used when you need te get some data into the flow from some stored proc. When you actually use the proc output. In reality: hardly ever needed. The only case is when you need to calculate the input parameters in the data flow, invoke the stored proc and process the output. For other cases (like audit, index operations, partition operations, etc) a Pre- and Post- SQL properties should be used. And this will act more like the Control Flow you mentioned.

Comment: I got the mapping to work following your suggestion :)

Comment: I meant to say I got the mapping to validate following your suggestion :) But it doesn't write the runtime statistics to the table yet (I'm not using the SP output, I need the Target and Source Rows as well as the run times from the previous mapping). Thank you!

Comment: Let me know if you'd be facing any issues. Good luck!

Comment: This is what I'm talking about, none of these can be done in Developer: 
1.Using SP transformation (connected). Import the SP from db to Informatica. 2. Unconnected: SP can also be used where it runs from an expression transformation or -Pre- or post-session.
3. Also the SP can also be called  / used at session  level.
Either in the below scenarios:
Pre-load of the Source
Post-load of the Source
Pre-load of the Target
Post-load of the Target